# Does OPC Historian server exists in between SCADA to OPC UA server?

Tags: plc, opc, scada

Is there a OPC Historian server in between? where PLC or SCADA connects to OPC UA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you've put one there.

I think your question needs a lot more information or it's going to get flagged.

Comment: Sorry this is all the information that i have. Is historian another server that acts between these opc server and scada?

Comment: It depends on the server. Sometimes the historian is another OPC UA client that connects to one or more servers and logs all the data, other times the OPC UA server itself also logs the data. Some SCADA systems also store their own historical data, which may or may not be exposed via OPC UA historical access.